# Is it possible to derive an explicit expression for the inverse branches of $f(x)=x + x^{1+p}\mod 1, p > 0, 0\leq x\leq 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, dynamical-systems, inverse

My dynamics course has talked a bit about the Pomeau-Mannville map, defined as $f(x)=x + x^{1+p}\mod 1,p > 0, 0\leq x\leq 1$. I was wondering whether there is any known trick or a special function that allows us to write explicitly the inverse branches of $f$. Plotting the function shows two inverse branches over the unit interval. But I don't have any clue on how to find the inverse, nor do I know whether it is possible

Comment: There is a [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial) solution and a closed form using special functions. However, does this solution apply to your question as it is also about dynamical systems?

Answer (score 1):

If you can already plot the function, there's very simple steps to find the inverse functions by mirroring with y=x line:
$$(x,f(x)) \\\rightarrow (f(y),y) $$

Usually it continues like this:
$$ \rightarrow (f^{-1}(f(t)),f^{-1}(t)) \\\rightarrow ((f^{-1} \circ f)(t),f^{-1}(t)) \\\rightarrow (Id_t(t),f^{-1}(t)) \\\rightarrow (x,f^{-1}(x))$$, but the 2nd one in the chain already describes the inverse function graph.

Comment: How would you use this method to find any of the inverse branches of the Pomeau-Mannville map?

Comment: it comes from the $f^{-1} \circ f = Id_t$.